# How to do a conditional branch in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I would like to execute a task in SSIS based on a condition. Specifically, I want to either create a table or clear it (truncate it), depending on if it already exists.

Currently I'm using a SQL task, where the SQL does the work, but I'm wondering if there is a better way...

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any benefit to splitting the logic into several SSIS UI tasks? Given that I think it is a matter of preference and style, I like to keep as much logic as possible in the SQL code, not the SSIS package UI tasks.

Comment: I have to agree with @Mike, packages with a lot of fancy UI tricks are much harder to maintain than those who perform alot of the action in the SQL tasks.

Comment: I agree in principal with Mike and @HLGEM. The bigger question here could be: Is this a good idea or not? I would say it depends. What comes next in the package that is made more effective by this change? For example: is there a good reason downstream why this package should branch? Maybe the right hand path that follows after truncate is totally different than the left hand path that follows after create table. If there is no material difference, then by all means keep solving it with one SQL task. Can depend also on your preference in terms of visualization: does this feel like clutter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is technically feasible by adding an expression to a precedence constraint. [Click here for the details](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140153.aspx). The basic steps are...

1. Create a package scoped variable @FoundMyTable that will hold a value of 1 if table exists and 0 if table does not exist
2. Set the value of @FoundMyTable via an execute SQL task named LookForMyTable that uses a select statement and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES to return a table count

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(1)AS table_count
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
     WHERE t.TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable';
   ```
3. Create two execute SQL tasks: TruncateMyTable and CreateMyTable
4. Connect LookForMyTable to both TruncateMyTable and CreateMyTable
5. Double click on the precedence constraint between LookForMyTable and TruncateMyTable >
   Expression and Constraint > @FoundMyTable == 1
6. Double click on the precedence constraint between LookForMyTable and CreateMyTable > 
   Expression and Constraint > @FoundMyTable == 0