# SSIS 2008 R2- Schedule Data flow task so that it only runs on Workday 1 - 2 Days

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SSIS package in visual studio 2008 which just contains a simple data flow task (ole DB source, flat file destination). However I need to add a constraint so that the task only executes on workday 1 minus 2 days, anyone know if this can be achieved?

No ideas at present, I am expecting the DFT to only execute on WD1- 2 days

Comment: What does "workday 1 minus 2 days" mean? Should it only be excuted on specific dates? Or should it be excuted every day, but apply some speical logic to the date that it processes?

Comment: It would only be executed on specific dates. In the example of November it would need to run on the 29th Nov. So in this example workday one is 1st December minus 2 working days

Comment: So this would run 12 times a year? What happens if for some reason the job fails to run one day. Can you run it the next day?

Comment: It's a file which is being produced for a third party and their requirement is to recieve the files on Wd1 --2 so in theory would run 12 times a year. I think we would need option for it to run later if required, but think expectation would be process would need to be fixed on day of failure if situation occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a SQL statement to work this out.

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN DATEPART(DAY,DATEADD(DAY,2,GETDATE()))=1 THEN 'Y' 
ELSE 'N' 
END
```

You run this in an execute SQL task, then capture the output then branch as required

Or you can use an SSIS expression to work it out (then you don't need to connect to the DB)

You do need to consider some logic in case your job fails on a given day. If you run the job a day later, what should you do?

I can add more details to this answer if this appeals to you

Comment: Thank you yes that would be good, we do have a calendar table in our DB so could use this in an execute sql task, never branched this out to data flow tasks befor so not sure how this aspect would work

Comment: Here's an example of conditional branching based off a DB value. Yes you should definitely use your calendar table to run the logic. I don't have any info on it so I can't suggest a query for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/20696335/1690193

Comment: Many Thanks I set up a pa kage using the calendar table and everything is working as it should